# JavaScript libraries for rectangle manipulation using Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'd like to create something similar to that of a UML / Flowchart Design tool. The user should be able to drag shapes onto the canvas, and then add text to the shape, resize the shape, reposition the shape, and link shapes together through angular lines.

## Question:

Are there any JavaScript Canvas libraries which I could build such an application on top of?

Feel free to ask me if you're unsure of what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks in advance!

## Note:

Any tutorials are greatly appreciated too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its not too complicated or large then SVG would probably be an easier bet.

[RaphaelJS](http://raphaeljs.com/) is probably the most popular SVG library.

Canvas libraries that could do something simple like this are [FabricJS](http://fabricjs.com/) and [KineticJS](http://www.kineticjs.com/), but I don't think either of them support the concept of links very well.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful. I'll have to weigh up the benefits of using SVG vs Canvas for this project!

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about a library, I don't use a library but do everything by myself by controling all the mouse events: mousedown, mouseup, mousemove, etc.

Maybe you can learn by reading the blog of this guy, Simon, he has nice tutorials like:

http://simonsarris.com/blog/510-making-html5-canvas-useful

http://simonsarris.com/blog/225-canvas-selecting-resizing-shape

Comment: Thanks, both of these tutorials are extremely useful.

Comment: It always feels weird to see my name in the wild